# passing thru exception on custom errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following in my web.config. This works fine but i'm wondering is it possible to catch the exception on this page. So lets say i throw an exception on "/Products/12345" i would like to write the exception message on "/Error"

```
<customErrors mode="On">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error"  />
</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - when you setup a new "Internet mvc app" template it is already setup for you at /Shared/Error.cshtml but you have to change it a bit to handle the details.
MVC3 uses [HandleError] globally to handle this.

Change the default page to be HandleErrorInfo such as:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Error</h2>

<p>
  Controller: @(((HandleErrorInfo)ViewData.Model).ControllerName)
</p>
<p>
  Action: @(((HandleErrorInfo)ViewData.Model).ActionName)
</p>
<p>
  Message: @(((HandleErrorInfo)ViewData.Model).Exception.Message)
</p>
<p>
  Stack Trace: @(((HandleErrorInfo)ViewData.Model).Exception.StackTrace)
</p>
```

Comment: btw- this is of course assuming you have a layout (ie master page) if not use Layout = null; instead

Comment: Is it possible to also get InnerException if available?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT my model is always null for some reason? Any help on this?